# Push dfferent variants to different remotes

Tags: git, push, githooks, gitattributes

I have a repository with two remotes (or even better: one remote with two `pushurl`s). One of these should receive the unaltered commits, as Git does regularly, but the other one should receive a slightly altered version.

For the purpose of this question, let us assume I want to run `sed '/\s*#/d'` over the files to remove all comments.

I do not have direct access to both remotes and thus can place no server side [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Is it possible to send out different variants to different remotes with Git?

Comment: Why would a hook not do a good job?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski as far as I understood, a hook could indeed alter local commits before they are sent. But local changes would affect both remotes. If I am wrong, feel free to put me right with an answer.

Comment: You need a server-side hook, which will alter the commits only on the remote it is installed on

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski that would possibly the most appropriate way to solve my dilemma. Unfortunately, I cannot place hooks into any of the remotes.

Comment: There is no other solution that will guarantee this behavior. Why can't you place them there?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski because one of the remotes is [github](https://github.com/) and the other one is [Arch Linux new User Repository](https://aur4.archlinux.org/). Both only allow git client access.